# Navigation Drawer can't navigate

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i'm trying to make a navigation to one of my fragment but I can't seem to invoke that fragment here's my code

**MainActivity.java**

```js
package ics115_4ite_lim.bookings;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import ics115_4ite_lim.bookings.Fragments.ScheduleFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        Fragment fragment = null;
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.schedule_fragment) {
            fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.driver_fragment) {

        } else if (id == R.id.transaction_fragment) {

        }

        

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and this is the fragment I want to go to

**ScheduleFragment.java**

```js
package ics115_4ite_lim.bookings.Fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout;
import com.daimajia.swipe.adapters.RecyclerSwipeAdapter;
import com.daimajia.swipe.util.Attributes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import ics115_4ite_lim.bookings.DividerItemDecoration;
import ics115_4ite_lim.bookings.R;
import ics115_4ite_lim.bookings.Student;

/**
 * Created by Mark Terrance on 12/7/2017.
 */

public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<Student> mDataSet;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView tvEmptyView;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Inflate the layout for this fragment_packages
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_fragment, container, false);
        initScheduleView(view);

        return view;
    }

    private void initScheduleView(View view){

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);

        // Layout Managers:
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        // Item Decorator:
        //mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider)));
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider)));

        mDataSet = new ArrayList<Student>();



        loadData();

        if (mDataSet.isEmpty()) {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        // Creating Adapter object
        SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), mDataSet);


        // Setting Mode to Single to reveal bottom View for one item in List
        // Setting Mode to Mutliple to reveal bottom Views for multile items in List
        ((SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setMode(Attributes.Mode.Single);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        /* Scroll Listeners */
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                Log.e("RecyclerView", "onScrollStateChanged");
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }
        });
    }


    // load initial data
    public void loadData() {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
            mDataSet.add(new Student("Student " + i, "androidstudent" + i + "@gmail.com"));

        }


    }


    private class SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerSwipeAdapter<SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> {


        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<Student> studentList;

        public SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Student> objects) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.studentList = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.swipe_row_item, parent, false);
            return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
            final Student item = studentList.get(position);

            viewHolder.tvName.setText((item.getName()) + "  -  Row Position " + position);
            viewHolder.tvEmailId.setText(item.getEmailId());


            viewHolder.swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut);

            // Drag From Left
            viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper1));

            // Drag From Right
            viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper));


            // Handling different events when swiping
            viewHolder.swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {
                    //when the SurfaceView totally cover the BottomView.
                }

                @Override
                public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout layout, int leftOffset, int topOffset) {
                    //you are swiping.
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
                    //when the BottomView totally show.
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartClose(SwipeLayout layout) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel) {
                    //when user's hand released.
                }
            });

        /*viewHolder.swipeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if ((((SwipeLayout) v).getOpenStatus() == SwipeLayout.Status.Close)) {
                    //Start your activity

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, " onClick : " + item.getName() + " \n" + item.getEmailId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });*/

            viewHolder.swipeLayout.getSurfaceView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, " onClick : " + item.getName() + " \n" + item.getEmailId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


            viewHolder.btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked on Map " + viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


            viewHolder.tvShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Share " + viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            viewHolder.tvEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Edit  " + viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


            viewHolder.tvDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipeLayout);
                    studentList.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, studentList.size());
                    mItemManger.closeAllItems();
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Deleted " + viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


            // mItemManger is member in RecyclerSwipeAdapter Class
            mItemManger.bindView(viewHolder.itemView, position);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return studentList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {
            return R.id.swipe;
        }


        //  ViewHolder Class

        public class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
            TextView tvName;
            TextView tvEmailId;
            TextView tvDelete;
            TextView tvEdit;
            TextView tvShare;
            ImageButton btnLocation;

            public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
                tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                tvEmailId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailId);
                tvDelete = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDelete);
                tvEdit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEdit);
                tvShare = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvShare);
                btnLocation = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried debugging it and I ended up on a null fragment

I don't know what's wrong because I just followed a tutorial

Help pls ? thanks :D

edit:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ics115_4ite_lim.bookings.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually do something with the `Fragment` you created.

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        Fragment fragment = null;
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.schedule_fragment) {
            fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.driver_fragment) {

        } else if (id == R.id.transaction_fragment) {

        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container_id, fragment).commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

- Make sure your fragment is not `null`, all your `if` branches should
  initialize it to something
- `R.id.container_id` should be an id of a ViewGroup in your layout that is empty and this is where the fragment will be placed.

Comment: I completely missed that! Thanks I will add those other fragments.

Comment: Thumbs up if it helps ya :P

Comment: I have a FrameLayout on my content_main.xml but it has an error when I replaced the container_id. any ideas or any step by step guide? really new on android

Comment: It can't find the id of the FrameLayout neither the content_main.xml

Comment: post your main XML where the container for fragments is

Comment: I edited the main post, I added the xml please see it

Comment: Can you also update your activity's code? where are you calling findViewById? and it returns null